# Excel - Comparing Multiple Columns

Tags: excel

Hoping someone can assist this Excel newbie...

Trying to figure out how to compare the values in columns B and C starting with B2 and C2 (they are paired together - B3 & C3, B4 & C4 also paired, etc) with the values in columns E and F (E2 and F2 are also paired together). Also need to be able to see if the paired values of B2 and C2 are listed anywhere within paired values in columns E and F.

Hope I'm not making this more confusing than it needs to be... example of data is listed below.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want to compare B2 + C2 with E2 + F2? 

OR

Do you want to search all of E+F for B2 + C2, then for B3 + C3 ...?

Comment: Hi... need to search all of E+F for B2+C2 pairings then for B3+C3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question:

```
=IF(AND($B2=$E2, $C2=$F2), [return value if true], [return value if false])
```

The second part is a bit trickier.  I would lean toward using a macro to solve this problem since it involves looping.

The logic goes like this:

- Does the `B2;C2` combination match with `E2;F2`, `E3;F3`, `E4;F4`, ...
- Does the `B3;C3` combination match with `E2;F2`, `E3;F3`, `E4;F4`, ...
- Continue with this loop to end of `Bn;Cn` combinations

Is this type of solution what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi... yes, thank you so much on the first part of my question and for the macro suggestion and logic... really appreciate it!

Comment: Why not use a Lookup? Maybe add some columns: G with CONCAT($B2,$C2), H with CONCAT($D2,$F2), I for row number (1,2,3,4...). Then two more columns - J for the LOOKUP function and K for the result. I would go that route first.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the alternative solution... will give it a try!

Comment: The loop should not be too hard to implement, I don't believe.  It is a quadratic-runtime nested loop which should run until both rows are empty.  Let me know if you need some help.